# Python/MySQL SELECT, Update and Fetch in same query

Tags: python, mysql

I want to `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in one query.

In my database, I have `category_id`s that needs to be checked. I want to select the last updated query by `DESC` and update it with `runs = runs+1`, so it counts up that and also automatically update the `last_update` field.

But for some reason, I can't fetch it

```
cursor.execute(
"UPDATE categorys as t1, 
(SELECT category_id 
 FROM categorys 
 ORDER BY last_update 
 LIMIT 1) as t2 
 SET t1.runs = t1.runs+1 
 WHERE t2.category_id = t1.category_id")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

`print(row)` gives me `None` but I need the `category_id` here

The update works and counts up the `runs+1` of the `last_update` `DESC`

Answer (score 1):

mysql update doesn't return value of data changed. It only returns the Query ran ok.

you would need to execute the select statement to return the category_id.